# eclipse build problem

Tags: eclipse, build, dependencies

when I try to build my Eclipse project, I get the following error message:

```
The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Can anybody help me to solve this problem? The Java-Build-Path contains the Plug-in-Dependencies-Library and org.eclipse.swt... is listed there.

I didn't have the problem last week (though nothing should have changed in the meantime).
But it's not the first time that I get this typ of error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I could solve the problem with creating a new workspace and importing my project.

Comment: Deleting the `.metadata` directory inside the Eclipse Workspace directory and then re-import all existing projects from file-system has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes encounter this kind of stranges error and the only solutions I found to solve it are the following ones (no specific order and sometimes one is enough sometimes not):

1. Select the project and clean ONLY this project, then rebuild
2. Clean all the workspace
3. Restart the workbench
4. Disable "automatic build", clean all, the build only your project
5. Remove the project from the workspace WITHOUT removing it from Hard drive and then import it again

I think this is a PDE issue.

Hope this can help,
Manu

Comment: Hi Manu, I've tried everything you suggested beside from point 3 (how do I restart the workbench?) but nothing seems to help...

Comment: File -> Restart. But it's the same than file exit and launching eclipse again.

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting that it's like closing and relaunching Eclipse... Is there anybody else who knows what could help?

Comment: This does not work with Eclipse Juno, the error stays the same.