# Build errors in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, build

I have a big problem, i can't compile my eclipse project.

I don't understand what is the problem. I have already searched for answer but i stay helpless!

Hier the build error in eclipse:

[image: errors occured during build]

Can you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Could be this bug {https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=158744}. The full stack trace should be in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project and do fix project properties, then do clean and build..if everything fails try restarting eclipse after doing above steps

Comment: Thanks for answer. what do you mean with "fiy project properties"? which properties should i fix?

Comment: Did you try checking for any project dependencies which you might have forgot to mention..check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/6840307/1396082